# Count upper and lower case characters in Java array

Tags: java

I have worked out how to loop through an array and count each letter and return. I have done this by comparing it to its ascii value. The issue I have is, I cannot make it take upper case as well. How do I set it to also count upper case letters?

```
package test;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class arrays {
    public static void array(char[] charAlphabet) {
        int intCount = 97;
        int intNumberof = 0;
        //sort the array into alphabetical order
        Arrays.sort(charAlphabet);
        //look at each character
        for(int x = 0; x < charAlphabet.length;) {
            //if the position of the character is equal to its place in the alphabet, increase the count
            if(charAlphabet[x] == intCount) {
                intNumberof++;
                x++;
            }
            //when it reaches the end of the letters, print it
            else {
                intCount++;
                //print the letter and the number of letters
                System.out.println(Character.toString(charAlphabet[x -1]) + " x " + intNumberof);
                intNumberof = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    //input
    public static void main(String[] dfsgsdg) {
        char[] charAlphabet = "aabcdefghijklmnoapqrstuvwxyaz".toCharArray();
        array(charAlphabet);

    }
}
```

--Edit--

Just realised that actually my logic is slightly off, in that it actually misses off the last character in the array, but if I remove the -1 on the print, it actually misses off the first.

Comment: The uppercase letters are off by 32, so you could just check the offset. It's probably easier to convert it to lower-case and check for equality though.

Answer (score 0):

Try "ABa" and it will not find "a" (97) as twice `intNumberof++`.

The same for "a22c".

Forget about sorting and check every letter for `charAlphabet[x].isUpperCase()` resp. `isLowerCase()`

Comment: Just realised that actually my logic is slightly off, in that it actually misses off the last character in the array, but if I remove the -1 on the print, it actually misses off the first.

Comment: Yes, rethink how to do it: more logical, short names, what needs to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can take each character as a String and then apply this logic.

```
String temp= str;
If(str.toUpperCase().equals(temp)){
  //It is uppercase
}
else{
//lower case
}
```